# What is the best ViewModel naming convention?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing an asp.net mvc2 project with a lot of views/partialviews. Reading on good MVC practices, I've been encourage to create ViewModels. Its really nice and makes sense to do so but I'm noticing recently that I can no longer easily remember what model is for what view. I'm hoping there is a nice naming convention for ViewModels that can handle large projects.

My question is can this situation be improved?

Comment: I've written a few slightly more detailed suggestions about [ViewModel naming conventions](http://www.appetere.com/Blogs/SteveM/April-2012/MVC-Framework-ViewModel-naming-conventions) in a blog post, which may be useful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I like to keep it simple, for instance, if you have an object named Folder:

**View = "FolderView.xaml"**

**ViewModel = "FolderViewModel.cs"**

Answer (score 3):

Make it simple:

```
ModelName = ViewName + "Model";
```

If you have model hierarchies, you sometimes need to pass the model from the view to partial views. In that case the above rule can be waived.

Answer (score 2):

If you are keeping your view models in the same assembly as your views, one trick I have used to help organize views with view models in addition to a simple naming scheme like {View Name}ViewModel for the view model class is to do the following:

1. Create your view class (Shell.xaml)
2. In the same location, add your view
   model class (ShellViewModel.cs)
3. Rename the view model class file to
   be the same name as the view, but
   append .model to the file path
   (Shell.model.cs)
4. Edit the project file (either
   manually or using the power command
   extensions in VS)
5. Locate the *Compile* element for
   the view model class in the project
   XML document
6. Add a child *DependentUpon* element
   whose content is the name of the
   view class
7. Save changes and reload the project

This will cause the view model class to be visually grouped along side the code-behind file for the view.

[image]

Comment: This looks interesting but I'm not sure whether or not it would be considered good practice. I'd be interested to hear other people's thoughts on this.

Comment: It is useful for visually organizing the view model with the view, the same way the codebehind is linked to the view. I think the best practice comes into play regarding whether you should have your view models in a separate class library from your view, which depends on your reuse and testing scenarios. On some projects, I have had the view models in another library, but in simplier projects have placed them in the same projects as the views.

Comment: It's interesting, but it doesn't fit well with the fact a viewmodel can be used by multiple views. Also, grouped files are often partial classes, which a viewmodel cannot and shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

For ASP.NET MVC I keep my view models in a `ViewModels.{Controller}` namespace and the class name is just `{Action}`. I don't use the ViewModel suffix just like how the view files don't have a View suffix.

Answer (score 0):

I've started going one step further and specifying if a ViewModel is used to generate a Form via EditorFor by ending the name with Form.  Helps keep forms vs. simple display models easily identifiable.